# Opening doc files as docx

Tags: macros, docx

I am using an application that currently can't handle Word 2007 or 2010 files. The application treats them as .doc files.

This means when opening them from the application, Word treats it as .doc rather than .docx causing random text to appear and the Office Converter Tool not to run.

I was wondering if there is a way for work to run a macro or maybe a command line that would either change the extension to .docx from .doc or force the compatibility pack to run?

Comment: It would really depend on the application, and how it opens files. What version of Office are you actually running? The reason I ask is that most such applications call Word to actually do the work for them, and if you have Word 2003, but have not added in the "Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint File Formats", it would fail. I realize that you probably have done this, but I can't take that for granted, so I am asking.

Comment: Your question is not comprehensible. It doesn't mean anything to open a file as docx. Do you mean that your unstated version of Word doesn't *save* as docx? Do you mean that your docx files are incorrectly named as "*.doc" and Word is believing this and not interpreting them correctly?

Answer (score 2):

[This MSDN blog page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx) should help you out.

> Microsoft has a bulk conversion utility that can convert multiple DOC files to DOCX files.  This blog post presents very basic information on its use.  This utility has been around for a while, but a fair number of people don’t know of its existence.  Because it’s a powerful tool designed to convert all files on a server (or even a bunch of servers), its use is a little cryptic.  This is fine for IT professionals, but if all you want to do is bulk convert a single directory of DOC files, this post shows what you need to do.

Comment: Sounds like the solution to the opposite problem.

Comment: Not from what I gathered. (Although you just made me question the OP) He said "[I want a macro] that would either change the extension to docx from doc or to force the compatibly pack to run".